# Spring Integration with Spring Boot - High Availability

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-integration, high-availability

A spring integration project pulls emails from Exchange Server using imap-idle-channel-adapter; it transforms the message; it invokes some SOAP webservices and persists data in DB using Spring Boot and JPA. All works fine.
This needs to be deployed in a four-weblogic-server cluster environment.

Could someone please help with some hints on what needs to be done? Is there any configuration needed?

Answer (score 0):

As long as your logic is just like you show and there is no any more endpoints polling shared resource, your are good so far do nothing more. The mail API has built-in feature to mark messages in the box as read or at least seen, so other concurrent session won’t poll those messages again.

Comment: Hi Artem, I deployed Spring Integration/Spring Boot app to Weblogic in a cluster of 4 servers. I changed POM.xml to build a WAR file, following below post. Emails are processed 4 times.

https://o7planning.org/11901/deploy-spring-boot-application-on-oracle-weblogic-server