# imap-idle-channel-adapter in a cluster environment

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, imap, weblogic12c

An application that uses Spring Integration (imap-idle-channel-adapter) and Spring Boot was deployed in a Weblogic Cluster environment (4 servers).
The SI adapter imap-idle-channel-adapter pulls emails from Exchange Server fine if it is deployed in one server.
However, if it is deployed in cluster (4 servers), the email is processed 4 times (one per each server).

**Question: Is there any configuration or good practice for deploying this type of application in a cluster environment?**

Using:

- Spring Boot 2.5.1
- Spring Integration Mail 5.5.0
- Weblogic 12c

A war file was created following this blog.

https://o7planning.org/11901/deploy-spring-boot-application-on-oracle-weblogic-server

The configuration of the imap-idle-channel-adapter and mail properties are like this.

```
  <int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter id="customAdapter"
     store-uri="imaps://[username]:[password]@imap.gmail.com/INBOX"
     channel="receiveChannel"
     auto-startup="true"
     should-delete-messages="false"
     auto-close-folder="false"
     simple-content="true"
     java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties"/>
  
  <util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
     <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
     <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
     <prop key="mail.store.protocol">imaps</prop>
     <prop key="mail.debug">false</prop>
  </util:properties>
```

Comment: I don’t think so; you could use different accounts on different hosts, but coordinating “first access” to a single account is not really something IMAP supports.

Comment: Similar question was asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68333194/spring-integration-with-spring-boot-high-availability

Answer (score 1):

Well, technically it must be like that because a default `SearchTerm` is to not pull messages which are `DELETED` or `SEEN`. If those flags are not supported by your mail server, then `USER` is used. And since you don't specify some custom, it is always the same on all your instances - `spring-integration-mail-adapter`.

However it feels like that Exchange Server sets those flags in async manner, since you claim that all your instances get the same message.

So, another way is to use something artificial in your application via shared metadata store and Idempotent Receiver: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#idempotent-receiver.

You may also make your own custom `SearchTermStrategy` to filter out messages from the mail box some other way, than what we try to do with those `SEEN` and `USER` in a default one: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/mail.html#imap-seen

Comment: FWIW, gmail is quick enough that it may be telling all four clients about new mail before the first of the four sets any flag. The only way I know about to deal with situations like this is to assign a second to each instance. If an instance discovers anything to do, it'll wait for a bit less than a minute until "its" second, check again and do the work.

Comment: You can also put the adapter in a "role" and use [Leadership Event Handling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/endpoint.html#leadership-event-handling) with Zookeeper so that only one of the instances is active at a time. Also see https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/endpoint.html#endpoint-roles and https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/zookeeper.html#zk-leadership